# Complete List of forbidden file and folder names for windows

Tags: windows

On Windows file names like com1.txt or lpt1.txt are forbidden. Is there a list of all forbidden file and folder names on windows (or forbidden chars in the file and folder names like :? ...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The list of invalid characters is:

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- * (asterisk)

Plus characters 1 to 31

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx)

But you should use `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars` and `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars` (or their equivalents) as recommended by FlipScript as a) it's neater and b) means that if the list ever changes you won't have to modify your application.

Comment: Would be awesome IF `GetInvalidPathChars` would be complete. For example the `?` character isn't in this array... Thus, making this completely useless...

Comment: Asterisk * is also not included in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()

Answer (score 9):

A list of reserved device names:

[http://www.blindedbytech.com/2006/11/16/forbidden-file-and-folder-names-on-windows/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120414111738/http://www.blindedbytech.com/2006/11/16/forbidden-file-and-folder-names-on-windows)

```
CON
PRN
AUX
CLOCK$ (NT and older)
NUL
COM1
COM2
COM3
COM4
COM5
COM6
COM7
COM8
COM9
LPT1
LPT2
LPT3
LPT4
LPT5
LPT6
LPT7
LPT8
LPT9
```

Comment: The link seems to be dead now.

Comment: @ayke wayback machine to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what platform you are using, but in .Net, you can use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars
```

and

```
System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars
```

To return invalid file name and path characters.

Comment: These methods are useless as the documentation itself states: "The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names."