# File creation through redirection fails in batch

Tags: batch-file, io-redirection

Do you know why I fail to create a file called "aux"?

```
$ type nul > a.txt
$ type nul > au.txt
$ type nul > aux.txt
File not found.
$ dir /b
a.txt
au.txt
```

Actually I have the same problem using the GUI... Here is a (potentially bad) translation of the error: "Specified peripheral device invalid.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8,
>   COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also
>   avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example,
>   NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces.

How? (but remember, not recommended)

```
type nul > "\\?\%cd%\aux.txt"
```

And remember that when done, you will need

```
del "\\?\%cd%\aux.txt"
```

Comment: Thx for the "how"! Do you know if Linux has similar recommendations?

Comment: @procrastinator, not sure. From memory, null (`0x00`) and `/` characters are forbidden, and `-` is not recommended as a starting character (argument parsing problems). Anything not colliding with an existing element should be allowed (but as said, from memory, don't trust me)

Answer (score 1):

AUX is a forbidden file name.

Answer in [Complete List of forbidden file and folder names for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195347/complete-list-of-forbidden-file-and-folder-names-for-windows)

Referring to http://web.archive.org/web/20120414111738/http://www.blindedbytech.com/2006/11/16/forbidden-file-and-folder-names-on-windows