# What is the valid printer name in Windows?

Tags: windows, validation, printing

I was tasked to create a screen to input a description and a printer name installed on the back-end server. This facility will be used in the front-end to print documents directly to the server's installed printers. The printer name input should be validated to only accept a valid printer name.

I searched in google and was not able to find a document or post that tells what are the valid/invalid characters for Windows printer names.

I just want to confirm with the Windows guys if someone knows what exactly are the documented valid/invalid characters for printers names.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an authoritative description in the specs however if you try and add a printer with an obviously incorrect name you get:

[image]

Clearly you need to avoid '\' and ',', it's probably a good idea to avoid '/' as well.

Answer (score -3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195347/complete-list-of-forbidden-file-and-folder-names-for-windows) post contains a list of all forbidden names in Windows. This applies to files and folders as well as device names.

Comment: If you find a question that has the exact same answer as another question here on Stack Overflow, you should flag it as a duplicate. Underneath the question's tags, you'll see a link called "flag". Click on it, it'll pop up a dialog box. Just FYI for the future; I've already marked this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Except that is wrong, I just created a Windows printer with a colon character which according to that post is invalid.